# Solidity | Smart Contract (Ethereum) transaction tracker API

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am finding the way to detect the specified transaction. For example, I want to detect if someone calls a method in my smart contract by making a transaction then, I want to make the transaction failed. 
So I'm looking for the API which can be monitoring the transactions or can be subscribing to the events. For instance, monitoring or tracking some special event. Do anyone know the great API? 
I am not an expert so Please let me know someone has an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your contract grants the right to someone to call a function, there is no way for you to stop him from doing this (when the transaction is already sent). Of course you can implement safety measures in the form of conditions that are checked when the function is called.